Drop message in function execution time - Spark
I'm trying to run some functions for my ETL pipelines and log them in the process, the issue is that when I call my function my log message is instantly shown, I want to display it during the execution.
This is an example of my func:
def ReadDataframe(path=None, format="parquet") -> DataFrame:
  

  if not isinstance(path, str) or not path:
    raise ValueError(logging.error("** LOAD ** : The 'path' parameter must be a non-empty string."))

  try:
    df = spark.read.format(format).load(path)
    logging.info("** LOAD ** : Data from path %s was successfully loaded into a DataFrame", path)
    return df
    
  except AnalysisException as e:
    logging.error("** LOAD ** : Error loading data into DataFrame. AnalysisException: %s", e)
    raise
  
  except Exception as e:
    logging.error("** LOAD ** : An unexpected error occurred while loading data into DataFrame: %s", e)
    raise

But when I call the function:
df = ReadDataframe(path=path)
The log message is instantly shown:

"** LOAD ** : Data from path %s was successfully loaded into a DataFrame"

I need to display the log when I execute the lazy code:
df.show()
Is there any way I can achieve this? Or any other approach to my problem?

Spark is evaluated lazily.
So spark.read.format(format).load(path) does not do anything.
It start executing only when you call action, e.g. count, collect, write, show etc.


df = spark.read.format(format).load(path)
logging.info("** LOAD ** : Data from path %s was successfully loaded into a DataFrame", path)
return df

If you write line 2 here it will execute anyway, because it's line-by-line execution. It has no idea weather df is executed or not.
So, better solution remove line 2 and call this before calling df.show()
